# Unable to save Stock Item

Tags: magento2, product, stock, save

I have installed Magento 2.2.6 in Google cloud VM. It is a fresh install and when I try to save a simple product, I get the following error:

> "Unable to save Stock Item"

My exception log shows the following error:

```
/var/www/html/app/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/StockItemRepository.php:183,
```

I'm stuck in this error and not sure about the solution:
I to tried decompile, upgrade, cache clean, cache flush, static deploymenI'mbut I'm unable to solve this issue.

I applied chmod 777 to the `/var/www/html/app/cod`e folder but unable to rectify the error.

Comment: Hey you need to run re-indexing first then you need to flush the cache then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried re-indexing and flushing the cache but I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I disabled Binary logging in the Google cloud SQL which allowed me to save the product. Anyway this might be a temporary solution hope for a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please Run the reindex command from magento root directory, Check following command to reindex,

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

And after reindex please flush the cache and check. hope it will work for you.
To flush the Magento cache run following command.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried re-indexing and flushing the cache but I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I solved it removing all Magento MSI modules through this package below, as you are running a Magento 2.2 I changed the package version to be the same.

```
composer require yireo/magento2-replace-inventory:2.2.*
```